# how can i on update item of tableview?

Tags: javafx-8

i have override the update item of TableCell in javafx 8 but when i scroll the items of tableview ,some items will be updated randomly

```
Column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> param) {
                return new TableCell<Person, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            if (item.booleanValue()) {
                                setGraphic(new ImageView(IconResource.getImage(ICON.FLAG)));
                            }
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `graphic` property of the cell is updated properly regardless of the item (or it the fact that it's "missing").

In your case you do not properly handle cells that go from `true` as item to `false` as item: You simply keep the graphic for `true` instead of removing it.

Furthermore I recommend keeping a reference to the `ImageView` to avoid recreating it:

```
Column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Spectrum, Boolean>>() {


    @Override
    public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> param) {
        return new TableCell<Person, Boolean>() {

            private final ImageView image = new ImageView(IconResource.getImage(ICON.FLAG));

            @Override
            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setGraphic(item == null || !item ? null : image);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you or your answer i tested this ,it will always setGraphic for one item. but when i have many items are true it will not update their cells

Comment: @Rom Sorry, stupid mistake. Of course the `ImageView` needs to be part of every cell, not of the factory... The updated version should work...